# Facebook login via php sdk gives redirect loop on live server

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have developed an facebook login with php sdk from (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/) and created an facebook app with sandbox mode disabled to work with.

In localhost or private host its working fine. But while move to the live server or actual domain redirect loop comes

And also i can't find any perfect solution for this question in stackoverflow.

Can anyone suggest me what is the exact reason for this redirect loop and also the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an alternate solution, By using CURL function with Graph API url,

First Request:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL&scope=email,read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access

Second Request:
To get access token,
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL&client_secret=YOUR_SECRET_KEY&code=$_GET['code']&display=popup

https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN FROM PREVIOUS REQUEST